# Loop through 3 tables in a .dat file

Tags: oracle, unix, loops

I have a .dat file, which contains a list of tables from a Oracle database. The file has 3 tables

```
Tab1
tab2
tab3
```

How can I loop through these 3 tables? I would expect 3 cycles (one per tab) but I don't know how do it.

Comment: Do you mean read the table data from oracle using sqlplus?

Comment: The connection with sqlplus it's ok. But the for loop: for ?? in ??
do i don't know how do it..or a while cicle..i think i have to cicle the file.dat right?

Answer (score 0):

I really do not see what you want, but in order to get somewhere I'm guessing.

```
while read table
do
  sqlplus -s username/password@oracle_instance <<-EOF
        select * from $table;
  exit
EOF
done < file.dat  > outputfilename
```

This reads ALL three tables.  It gets the table names ($table) from file.dat, it writes all of the data  into one file, outputfilename.

Comment: sorry this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605578/unix-shell-read-array-content-in-a-for-loop